# Can you compute $P(A)$ if you know $P(A|B), P(A|C), P(B)$ and $P(C)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The agent is described as either loyal or not-loyal. The probability that the agent is loyal is
given by ‘p.’ The negotiations can reach two outcomes for the country: favorable and
unfavorable. The outcome of the negotiations may give an indication of whether the
agent is loyal or not.

Suppose that the negotiations have an unfavorable outcome for the country. Suppose that
$p($loyal$)=.8$, $p($unfavorable$|$loyal$)=.5$, and $p($unfavorable$|$not loyal$)=.7$. Use Bayes
Theorem to calculate the probability that the agent is not loyal.

My question is: how can I use Bayes Theorem in this case when I don't know $p($unfavourable$)$ or $p($favourable$)$? Is it even possible to compute $p($not loyal$│$unfavourable$)$ from the data given?

Comment: I'm not asked to compute P(not loyal), but P(not loyal│unfavourable). Note that it is said that we shall start from the supposition that the negotiations have an unfavourable outcome. Theoretically, the solution should be: p(not loyal│unfavourable)=(p(unfavourable│not loyal)*p(not loyal))/(p(unfavourable))
Unfortunately, I can't get around p(unfavourable). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The law of total probability says:

$$P(\text{unfavorable})=P(\text{unfavorable}|\text{loyal})P(\text{loyal})+P(\text{unfavorable}|\text{not loyal})P(\text{not loyal})=.5\cdot .8+.7\cdot .2$$

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Forgot about P(A)=P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|C)P(C)